# Hadoop HDFS: DateNode directory on system partition?

Tags: linux, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs, quota

We run out of space on our Hadoop Cluster that is setup in this way:

- 1x 1TB HDD / <- Ubuntu System Partition
- 3x 1.5TB HDD /data1 /data2 /data3 <- HDFS Data Volumes

The system partition is almost not used (97% free) and will not be used for tasks unrelated to hadoop.

Is it safe to add the system partition as HDFS data dir to the DataNode Configuration?

I'm afraid that Hadoop fills up the partition and make the system unusable.

The best way would probably to setup seperate lvm volumes or re-partition the disk. But I would avoid going this way.

Does hadoop respect unix quotas? E.g. if I add an directory from the system partition and restrict the hadoop user via quota to only use e.g. 0.5TB would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Hadoop uses general file-writing APIs to write block data and would respect Unix-level quotas. In addition, there is the config property `dfs.datanode.du.reserved` which lets you set a reserved space per volume (applied to all volumes) that the DataNodes will not consider writing onto.

However, it is generally bad practice to allow writes into the OS mount. If you envision looking for more storage space eventually (given that you are hitting limits already), it may be better to buy a few more disks and mount them on the DataNodes.

Comment: Thanks, For now I've went with `dfs.datanode.du.reserved`. I understand your sentiment regarding using the os partition but more disks are not an option at the moment and the space will only be used for HDFS not for MapReduce intermediate data. I hope I'm on the safe side with this till we get more machines with more space.

Comment: To be extra safe, disallow use of `mapred.local.dir` over this mount-point, as that is used by user-run logic and can cause space fillups, even if just for transient data.